# WAMP Server not displaying images

Tags: php, e-commerce, wamp, opencart

I'm having a problem which I don't know what to search in google. Basically I have installed WAMP server and Installed OPen Cart

I am able to view my ECommerce site on my local computer but when I open it in on a remote computer it doesn't load any images. It only shows texts

My scenario:
if I load the PHP page at

http://192.168.1.101/

it works fine. I am able to view the WAMP server page which I put in the root directory  but when i load the ecommerce pages at

http://192.168.1.101/clothing/

it doesn't load the images. As if the PHP scripts are not working on it. Funny thing is it works fine on my local machine when I browse

http://127.0.0.1/clothing/

Thanks for any help!

Comment: Not appearing on the admin page or the front page or both?

Comment: The  WAMP Server Configuration Page works fine. It's only the OpenCart Page not appearing. It's not just images, it's like the whole PHP script is not running. No tables, no columns and etc. Just plain dummy texts. When I click on a link on the e-commerce page it says page cannot be found.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add these lines (if isn't there yet) in `<opencart main directory>/config.php` :

```
// HTTP
define('HTTP_SERVER', 'http://192.168.1.101/clothing/admin/');
define('HTTP_CATALOG', 'http://192.168.1.101/clothing/');
define('HTTP_IMAGE', 'http://192.168.1.101/clothing/image/');

// HTTPS
define('HTTPS_SERVER', 'http://192.168.1.101/clothing/admin/');
define('HTTPS_IMAGE', 'http://192.168.1.101/clothing/image/');
```

Note the address `192.168.1.101` and directory name `clothing`. You have to change it everytime you rename the directory or access your site from different address.

Comment: Salam, Thanks for the answer really appreciate it. But I'm still getting the same problem.

Comment: Open your erroneous web page, then view the HTML source. Find `<base href=...`, `<link href=...` how does those lines look like?

Comment: Great idea. THey're both the same. THe only difference is that the working one has <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?> on the first line

Answer (score 0):

How are the links formed? You probably need to alter them as it seems that they are tied to your localhost (ie. maybe images are linked: http://127.0.0.1/image_file.jpg) rather than being relative (ie. ./image_file.jpg) - which would explain why it isn't appearing when you change IP addresses.

Answer (score 0):

I had same problem but i found the solution,..is that the image which you want to insert into your web page keep into.folder.. C:\wamp\www 
so in this way your wamp server can find the located image then this code will execute`<img src="exapmle.jpg" width="400" height="500" >`