# Display image wamp with html/php

Tags: php, html, laravel, wamp, wampserver

I'm actually new in this so this may sound ridiculous, but I'm really having struggle at this.

I want to load an image from my wamp server in my PHP file, where should I put the image? And how can I access to it?

I've tried

```
<img data-src="http://localhost:8000/images/logo.jpg" alt="Generic placeholder image">
```

and so on, but nothing is working, is there something I am missing?

Comment: what you have tried so far ...?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [WAMP Server not displaying images](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9240135/wamp-server-not-displaying-images)

Comment: Why are you using `data-src` and not just `src`? You should place it in the same directory where your PHP files are or one if its subdirectories. You can use relative path `image/logo.png` instead of absolute one with `localhost` in it.

Comment: Because you're using Laravel, you need to make a directory named `images` inside of your `public` directory, then place your logo there. Drop the `data-` from your `data-src`.

Comment: umh,  I've create in C:\wamp64\www\myproject\public a folder names images and put there an image. Now i should just type? data-src="images/logo.jpg"

Comment: Thank for your time sirs , I've solved!

Answer (score 1):

On server and on local are the same thing you can use **relative** path.

**Example**

```
 -page.html
 -images
    - image.jpg
```

in your page.html

`<img src="./images/image.jpg">`

Comment: This worked for me thanks , this means if i will use a vps this won't be the same?

Comment: @CristianoSoleti Relative path always working, that's why you should avoid to use url path

Answer (score 0):

if the path of file is ok then this will display your image 
- try to open file in browser http://localhost:8000/images/logo.jpg
if it works then the file should display
use img src="http://localhost:8000/images/logo.jpg" alt="Generic placeholder image" instead of data-src

Comment: Oh well , I don't even know why I was using data-src  , I'm just trying to learn things putting my self in projects , really thanks for your time

Answer (score 0):

Consider the following ficticious folder structure - the dots here signify a level in the heirarchy ( ie: subfolders )

```
.document root
    ..css
    ..images
        ...jpg
        ...gif
        ...bmp
    ..includes
    ..js
    ..pages
        ...admin
        ...user
        ...gallery
    ..etc etc
```

Root relative paths would be a path that is relative to the document root, such as:-

```
/images or /css
```

A folder relative path, from with say the pages directory might be

```
../images/jpg
```

The dots, in the above, mean to go up a level in the folder heirarchy

The easiest and generally more common path to use would be root relative and for you use you could simply use the following if you have uploaded the logo.jpg file to the images directory.

```
<img src="/images/logo.jpg" alt="Generic placeholder image" />
```

It should be noted that in the original you had used a `dataset` attribute value rather than the required `src` value expected by images.

Comment: Yeah I'm actually trying to learn things but i got confused, so dataset has no meaning for this purpose?

Comment: Correct - to display images it is the `src` attribute that you need to set. You could, with some trickery, perhaps use the `data-src` attribute but that would involve css

Comment: Perfect sir , now it's clean . Thank you for your time