# How do I get my image to open in my localhost (WAMP)

Tags: php, image, wamp

I am working on an index.php file which is saved on Wamp in a 6-php folder in htdocs folder. I am trying to make a full page background image. I downloaded a picture from unsplash and saved it as background.jpg in the 6-php folder on Wamp. When I tried to get the image to show in http://localhost/6-php/index.php/, it didnt open. Al the text shows, it is just the image thats not opening. When I open it as http://localhost/6-php/ then the image shows but when I add /index.php/ the picture is gone and only the text displays.

I have tried downloading different images from different sites. I've tried saving it in different folders.

```
html { 
      background-image: url(background.jpg) no-repeat center center fixed; 
      -webkit-background-size: cover;
      -moz-background-size: cover;
      -o-background-size: cover;
      background-size: cover;
    }
```

I also tried only `<img src="background.jpg">` with no result.

I expect "background.jpg" to be a full-page background image on my index.php file.

Comment: Have you tried to open it with **http://localhost/6-php/index.php** without **/** at the end?

Comment: Have you checked the permissions of the image files, and of the containing folder?
See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9240135/wamp-server-not-displaying-images

Comment: Kausha Mehta, thank you very much. After endless struggles, I eventually realized the / does not belong there. And now everything works fine. Such a small problem that caused such a big headache for the past couple of days :)

Answer (score 0):

The path for the image matters. there are 2 optins to mention the path of the image

`path of image htdocs/project/images/background.jpg 
path of css  htdocs/project/css/style.css
path of index.php htdocs/project/index.php`

1. Relative path 
   path of the image starts from the base file which is trying to access the file

   style.css

   `body { 
         background-image: url('../images/background.jpg')
   }`

   index.php

   `<img src="../images/background.jpg">`
2. absolute path

   path of the image starts from the htdocs folder

   style.css

   `body { 
         background-image: url('/project/images/background.jpg')
   }`

   index.php

   `<img src="/project/images/background.jpg">`